# Set output of a command to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe, io-redirection

I want to get the number of files modified before 10 days to a variable.
I can get number of files using

```
forfiles /P "D:\files" /S /D -10  | find /c /v ""
```

But when i try to assign it to a variable using FOR it gives error.
Command I used in FOR is

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('forfiles /P "D:\files" /S /D -10  | find /c /v ""') DO set today=%i
```

It actually works fine when I remove `| find /c /v ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('forfiles /P "D:\files" /S /D -10  ^| find /c /v ""') DO set today=%i
```

in this case you need to escape the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the FIND command to count how many occurrences it finds but you don't need to.  You could just use the set command to iterate a variable.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('forfiles /P "D:\files" /S /D -10') do @set /a count+=1
```